# Why the export the Graphics or Image to local file

Tags: built-in-symbols

I note the `Put` cannot export the `Graphics` or `Image`,I mean this code will be failure.

```
Image[Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}]] >> "plot.png"
```

But the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put.html) of `Put` don't mention this.Have I missed something or I have made any syntax error?

Comment: `Put` writes the  expression to the file. If you open your `plot.png` in a text editor it will become clear what happened.

Comment: Use `Export` to write to a specific file format.

Comment: @chuy You mean `Put` cannot export a image file?

Comment: That's simply not what `Put` does.

Comment: The intent of Put is to save human readable Mathematica text. If you want something saved as PNG, JPG, EPS, etc... use Export.

Comment: "this code will be a failure" I object very much to this statement. The documentation says that "`expr >> filename` writes `expr` to a file" and this is **exactly** what it does, also in the case of `Graphics` or `Image`.

Comment: @C.E. Thank.I just think *EVERTHING* is express in *MMA*.So I thought the `Put` can do this.

Comment: @yode Everything is an expression, even `Graphics` and `Image`. That's why it can do it. If `Graphics` were something else, then it couldn't have done it, because there would be no expression to write to the file. Now, because `Graphics` is an expression, `Put` can write that expression to a file.

Comment: @C.E. I see it eventually.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here we "put", and then "get" the file:

```
Image[Plot[x, {x, 0, 2}]] >> "plot.png";
<< "plot.png"
```

Note that it returns the plot, exactly as it should! It also works if you leave off the `Image` command. In both cases, Put `>>` writes an expression to the file, that can be read back in by Get `<<`.

Comment: I find your answer misleading, as the file generated is not a `.PNG` file, but a text file with a *Mathematica* expresion, `Image[RawArray["UnsignedInteger8", {{{0, 0, 0, 0}, ....}], 
 "Byte", ColorSpace -> "RGB", Interleaving -> True]`